# Linux sed - finding a wildcard string with no spaces in it

Tags: sed, regular-expression

The **sed** command can use a full stop to find a wild card symbol, and so **.*** retrieves everything on the line.

Is it possible to say that I wish any symbol at all except (in this case) spaces? So:

`FredSmith` - would be valid

`Fred&Ginger` - would be valid

`6times7` - would be valid

`One too many` - would **not** be valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
echo "One too many" | sed -n '/^[^[:space:]]*$/p'
```

The above command returns nothing

---

```
echo "FredSmith" | sed -n '/^[^[:space:]]*$/p'
FredSmith
```

While the latter prints `FredSmith`

---

- `[:space:]` - POSIX character class for space characters
- `/^[^[:space:]]*$/p` - means "print match if it contains only non-space characters `[^[:space:]]`" (used *negated* character class)

Comment: Ideal - thank you! Out if curiosity can you check against other characters, so a string that has no 'Z's in it for example?

Comment: @HugMyster, welcome. Yes, to match the string containing any character(including space) except `Z` character - use pattern `/^[^Z]*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Use negated character classes (`[^ ]` or `[^[:space:]]`) as Roman showed, or invert the match as below. Which one is better depends on the surrounding structure.

```
$ cat foo.txt
with space
spaceless
$ sed '/ /d'  < foo.txt     # (d)elete the line on match
spaceless
$ sed -n '/ /!p' < foo.txt  # (p)rint if the pattern does not (!) match
spaceless
```